# Ajax.net - Improve Page Load Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, load-time

here's my problem. I'm developing a website that will allow users to book hotels all around the world, just like booking.com, expedia.com, etc.

When the user searches for hotels in a certain city, I connect through Web Services with different providers, and then show the results. In almost every provider this means:

1) Calling a method in WS that returns available hotels in the city for selected dates. For each of these hotels:

- 2) Read from a very large XML files (usually more than 1) to obtain static information like address, phone, fax, description, services, etc.
- 3) Call a second method in WS to get available rooms information.
- 4) Show result

The problem I'm having has to do with page load time, which is a key factor in these Websites.

The first call to the WS (point 1), it's something necessary in which there's not much I can do, so I have to accept this time. The other two points are also necessary, but my intention is to improve the user experience by **showing hotels as they load**.

Let's say you are looking for hotels in Buenos Aires. You enter "Buenos Aires" as your destination, and hit the "Buscar" button. As you may notice, a loading message is shown until the following page has been completely loaded. Instead of waiting for all hotels to load, what I would like to do, which I think will improve user's experience is:

1. When user hits "Buscar" button, immeadiately send user to HotelList page
2. Show each hotel as their information is obtained, and a message on the top saying something like "Loading 1 of XXX hotels"... "Loading 2 of XXX hotels" ...

I've been looking for ajax examples that would describe how to achieve this, but haven't found any clear articles. I would really much appretiate is someone could point me out in the right direction.

Thanks!

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Tried using multi-threading but results aren't displayed.
I'm showing the results using a Literal Control. Here's a piece of the code:

HotelList.aspx

```
<asp:Literal ID="HotelesResultadoBusqueda" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

HotelList.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    ...
    ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(CargarHoteles);
    Thread thread = new Thread(job);
    thread.Start();
}

private void CargarHoteles()
{
    // Load Hotels
    ArrayList hotels = WebService......
    foreach(Hotel hotel in hotels)
    {.....}
    ....
    this.HotelesResultadoBusqueda.Text = "...";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Re "as they arrive", the simplest thing there is to build a (thread-safe) queue of pending items at the back-end, I.e. New results go in the queue - and have your JSON query poll every few seconds for new data in the queue (for that session).

Re performance; just profile it and attack the bits that the profile shows is hurting. Pre-loading the XML into some indexed structure (maybe even a database) would be my main guess...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm not sure if I fully understand what you said. Are you suggesting creating a new thread for loading the results? Is there any documentation that could point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: @Gonzalo, yes - to return *anything* to the client, you'll have to finish the current request; so indeed you'll need to do the rest on some kind of worker. There are lots of ways of doing that, depending on how you want to coorddinate it.

Comment: Marc, I just tried using multi-threading but had no luck. I just pasted a piece of my source code in the post so you could see what I was going for. If there's an easier way of doing this, please advise! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea, the goal is to cache the results of your CargarHoteles() hotels function.  Because you are caching it you can have a background process do the work while the user interface responds quickly.

When the client first asks for information about a set of parameters the service return a unique id for that set of parameters (it looks to see if it is already in the cache and returns that if it exists).  When the client gets the unique id it starts asking the server for some results -- if they are already in the cache they come back right away -- or a subset comes back with an indication of how much of the search is done.

On the server side you have a worker process (or processes -- this solution allows you to toss more machines/process at the task if there is a good way to do so, for example a task for every xml file.)  These workers are solving the problem and putting the results in the cache, when they are done they flag that cache item as finished.  The next time the client requests more information it learns it has all the results.

Note that this design is compatible with Marc's suggestion, that is the queue he talks about is the results which are being built as an entry in the cache.

One of the nice features of this solution is if there is a lot of interest in one location (everyone is going to the Olympics!) your website gets faster.

I hope this is clear.  Post questions if it is not and I will try and explain more.

Comment: Hogan, thanks for the response! 

That's a good idea, caching results with a unique id related to the search parameters. I haven't used this technique before but from what I've read it's used in a similar way to Session and ViewState, right? 

If the unique id isn't in the cache, meaning that the search hasn't been done before or results have been removed due to low memory, I need to load the hotel's information by reading the XML files. How would you suggest improving this response time? How can I show results as they load instead of waiting for all of them to load?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking for some information regarding caching in ASP.NET, I found this post: [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachingaspnet.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachingaspnet.aspx). In the second paragraph it says _some websites have page creation engines which create all pages in one go and save them as HTML pages which are then served to the users_. If I'm not mistaken, [http://www.booking.com](http://www.booking.com) uses this technique, because the results are displayed in a HTML file. Is this a solution that could be used in my case?

Comment: If I was doing it I would store the cache on an SQL server -- this will also make the cache available for longer (or as long as you like) it seems with this kind of system you don't need to refresh the cache very often -- every few days maybe? -- having them in a DB means they will have a longer life.

Comment: Booking is a crazy site... the search results page is 28680 lines long!  It looks like they are using A9 as their data store but not using and JavaScript frameworks... crazy.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is not to use cache, but to store the search results in a database with a unique id related to the search params, right? The problem here is that search results change over time.. Providers (hotels) can change their rates, or hotels may go out of stock (no rooms left). So let's say I search for hotels in NY today from 21/05 - 28/05, if I make this same search tomorrow, results might change.. So I don't know if caching might be a good option, but if it was, it definitely needs to have a short duration.. What do you think?

Comment: The caching is serving two goals -- 1) to speed up multiple requests for the same information and 2) to allow for multiple parts of your system to reference the information, the initiator, the workers, and the displayer.  dbs are really good at handing and resolving multi-client access to the same data.  You can set the expire on the data in the cache to whatever you want minutes, hours days -- maybe different depending on the data.